# When coding in PHP how do I get the code to go to the index.php file with different file paths

Tags: php

I am not sure just how to ask this...

```
www.example.com/ 

www.example.com/user/list

www.example.com/user/add
```

How can I make all paths get caught so I can have it go to example.com/index.php and then I can decide what files I want to pull in from the paths...

Instead of doing:

```
www.example.com/index.php?e=user&a=list

www.example.com/index.php?e=user&a=add
```

I want something like this:

```
www.example.com/user/list

www.example.com/user/add
```

I am not sure if this code will be on a windows server or Unix server.  Not sure if I will have .htaccess or not.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the `.htaccess` file !

the `.htaccess` is a simple file placed in the root directory and allows you to play with the directories and redirect any request to a specific file.

so for example, you can redirect any request for `example.com/user/add` to `example.com/index.php?e=user&a=add`

and the user will only type and see `example.com/user/add` in the address bar. but the actual file that is displayed is `example.com/index.php?e=user&a=add`

**I will take you through the steps needed to achieve that:**

1. in order to display `example.com/user/add` instead of
   `example.com/index.php?e=user&a=add` first you will need to create a
   hidden file which starts with a period and then `htaccess` and that file should be placed in the main directory
2. then open that file and write into it the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^user/add index.php?e=user&a=add [NC]
```

**Note:**

but that will redirect the exact same url `example.com/user/add`. if you wanted the `user` to be a variable so it could be anything such as `example.com/hello/add` you will need to change your `.htaccess` content to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/add index.php?e=$1&a=add [NC,L]
```

so know {user} is a variable and will be redirected to `index.php?e={user}&a=add`

Comment: So one more quick question if I waned the add to be a variable as well.  would i do this?     RewriteRule ^(.*)/^(.*) index.php?e=$1&a=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: if the path is www.example.com/app/users/add   I am testing this for now on xampp can it be in a sub folder to cover children folders or does it have to be in the root only?

Comment: @NathanStanford if you waned the {add} to be a variable as well, you would do this: RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?e=$1&a=$2 [NC,L]